# how to send request to django database (case: the database has foreignKey)

Tags: reactjs, django

I am learning reactjs and django by making a blog but I have a question: how to post a request to server when the database has ForeignKey field ?

Example: I am making the comment section

Can someone help me to solve this ? Thanks for helping !

this is my code !

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 116)
    content = models.TextField()
    user_token = models.TextField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 116, null = True)
    comment = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: How are you creating the comments? Are you using serializers? A form?

Comment: I am using serializer, I am making the comment section for my django reactjs blog, but I am having a trouble that I can't send data to server. I don't know how to fix this so if you know how to fix this can you help me. this is my Repository
https://github.com/KhanhGamer1601/Blog

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the comments attached to an article, you could make a query in your related view in *views.py* like so:

`comments = Comment.objects.get(article=[Insert your desired article primary key here])`

If you have not set your primary key on *Article*, which is the case in the code snippet you shared, your primary key will be  an integer automatically incremented by Django as you create Articles.

Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/

If you do not want *[Insert your desired article primary key here]* to be a meaningless integer, you could set your *Article*'s primary key to be the title, like so:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 116, primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    user_token = models.TextField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

You would then query the related comments this way:

```
comments = Comment.objects.get(article=[Insert your article's title here])
```

Finally, if you do not want to change the primary key, try:

```
comments = Comment.objects.get(article=Article.objects.get(title=[Insert your article's title here]))
```